# How can i access a objecct that must be declared inside a function?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to make the imported obj model to move with the help of three.js, but due to formatting problem, the obj object must be declared inside a function, and i am not able to access it outside the function, even if i pre-declared a variable outside the function to point to thee object. How can i access the object in this way?

```
import * as THREE from 'https://unpkg.com/three@0.126.1/build/three.module.js';

import { OrbitControls } from 'https://unpkg.com/three@0.126.1/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';

import {OBJLoader} from "https://unpkg.com/three@0.126.1/examples/jsm/loaders/OBJLoader.js";

import {MTLLoader} from "https://unpkg.com/three@0.126.1/examples/jsm/loaders/MTLLoader.js";

import * as GUI from "https://unpkg.com/dat.gui@0.7.7/build/dat.gui.module.js";

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();

renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth,window.innerHeight);

document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

const scene = new THREE.Scene();

var keyLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(new THREE.Color('hsl(30,100%,75%)'),1.0);
var fillLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(new THREE.Color('hsl(240,100%,75%)'),0.75);
var backLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff,1.0);

keyLight.position.set(-100,0,100);
fillLight.position.set(100,0,100);
backLight.position.set(100,0,-100).normalize();

scene.add(keyLight);
scene.add(fillLight);
scene.add(backLight);


const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
    75,
    window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight,
    0.1,
    1000
);

const planeGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(100,100);
const planeMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: 0xffffff,
    wireframe: false,
});

var plane = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeometry,planeMaterial);
scene.add(plane);
plane.rotation.x = -0.5 * Math.PI;

const gridHelper = new THREE.GridHelper(100);
scene.add(gridHelper);

const gui = new GUI.GUI();
const options = {
    planeColor: '#ffea00',
    wireframe: false 
};

gui.addColor(options,'planeColor').onChange(function(e){
    plane.material.color.set(e);
});

gui.add(options,'wireframe').onChange(function(e){
    plane.material.wireframe = e;
});

const orbit = new OrbitControls(camera,renderer.domElement);
camera.position.set(0,2,7.5);
orbit.update();

const spotLight = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff);
scene.add(spotLight);
spotLight.position.set(-50,50,0);
spotLight.castShadow = true;
spotLight.angle = 0.2;

const sLightHelper = new THREE.SpotLightHelper(spotLight);
scene.add(sLightHelper);

gui.add(spotLight,"angle",-1,1,0.01).name("angle");
gui.add(spotLight,"penumbra",0,1,0.01).name("penumbra");
gui.add(spotLight,"intensity",0,100,0.01).name("Intensity");

let house = undefined;

const mtlLoader = new MTLLoader();
mtlLoader.load(
    '../source/MaryStanfordLifeboatHouse02.mtl',
    (materials)=>{
        materials.preload();
        console.log(materials);

        const objLoader = new OBJLoader()
        objLoader.setMaterials(materials)
        objLoader.load(
            '../source/MaryStanfordLifeboatHouse02.obj',
            function(object){
                scene.add(object);
                house = object;
                house.rotation.x = 1/2 * Math.PI;
                house.rotation.y =  Math.PI;
            },
            function(xhr){
                console.log((xhr.loaded / xhr.total) * 100 + '% loaded')
            },
            function(error){
                console.log("Object error")
            }
        )
    },
    (xhr) => {
        console.log((xhr.loaded / xhr.total) * 100 + '% loaded')
    },
    (error) => {
        console.log("Material Eror")
    }
)


    const textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();

    textureLoader.load(
        '../img/doge.jpg',
        function ( texture ) {
            scene.background = texture;
        },
        undefined,
        function ( err ) {
            console.error( 'An error happened.' );
        }
    );


    function animate(){
        // house.position.x += 1;
        renderer.render(scene,camera);
        sLightHelper.update();
    }

    renderer.setAnimationLoop(animate);
    window.addEventListener('resize',function(){
        camera.aspect = window.innerWidth/this.window.innerHeight;
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth,window.innerHeight);
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> // house.position.x += 1;

This line breaks because you access the variable too early. Keep in mind that the model is loaded asynchronously and you have to honor this circumstance when accessing it. As simple fix to avoid runtime errors is:

```js
if ( house !== undefined ) house.position.x += 1;
```

Another option is that you only start animating when all assets have been loaded.

Comment: Oh thats why, thx a lot